# How to compare to none

Tags: rebol

I have the following block of data:

```
client: ["id" "1234" "name" "foobar" "custom_ip" none]
```

Strangely, comparing to "none" never seems to work.

```
if none = (select client "custom_ip") [print "YAY!"]
```

Though when I `print select client "custom_ip"` it returns "none".

Why is this?  What can I do to determine that that value is none?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between a literal *value of type NONE!* and a WORD! with the spelling `NONE`.

One can *(rightfully, IMO)* call it a bug that the console does not differentiate these when giving you the output of an expression:

```
>> none  ;-- a word! that will be looked up to get its value
== none  ;-- that value, and it's *not* actually a word!
```

To get a less deceptive response from the console of the value that the `none` word evaluated to in that case, we can use mold/all

```
>> print mold/all none
== #[none]
```

Or you can just show the type of the result instead of the result itself:

```
>> type? none
== none!
```

Although that's deceptive in a sense for similar reasons, as it looks like the word NONE! when it's actually a datatype...

```
>> type? type? none
== datatype!
```

Anyway, what you actually got in your example was the word none, hence:

```
>> if 'none = (select client "custom_ip") [print "OH..."]
OH...
```

Deceiving console output aside, it's doing a predictable thing.  There is actually a shorthand for `#[none]` currently in Rebol3 for literal nones of a `#`:

```
>> client: ["id" "1234" "name" "foobar" "custom_ip" #]
>> if none = (select client "custom_ip") [print "HMM..."]
HMM...
```

But construction syntax is in flux in general; so it's hard to say what the ultimate answer will be.

Mostly just be aware of the distinction between the word NONE and a value of type NONE!, despite the basic console's dodgy output.  *(I'll mention that [Ren Garden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0exDvv5WEv4), for instance, uses MOLD/ALL)*

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!  I'm getting that block from the MySQL library so I don't know if its possible to have it replace none with #.

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon If it uses the word `none`, and does that with consistency...you may just have to test for that literal word.  I guess the problem would be if it is giving you a literal none sometimes, and a none! value sometimes; you could write an **any-none?** helper as an inelegant workaround that accepts either. :-/  But if you find the time to philosophize about it, there's chat...

Answer (score 1):

For the description, look at @HostileFork's answer, here's just some code I would use in such case:

```
unless get select client "custom_ip" [print "YAY!"]
```

See the `GET` function to evaluate NONE word!.